# Getting Nested Object Property Value Using Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address EmployeeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I have an instance of the employee class as follows:

```
    var emp1Address = new Address();
    emp1Address.AddressLine1 = "Microsoft Corporation";
    emp1Address.AddressLine2 = "One Microsoft Way";
    emp1Address.City = "Redmond";
    emp1Address.State = "WA";
    emp1Address.Zip = "98052-6399";

    var emp1 = new Employee();
    emp1.FirstName = "Bill";
    emp1.LastName = "Gates";
    emp1.EmployeeAddress = emp1Address;
```

I have a method which gets the property value based on the property name as follows:

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object obj ,string propertyName)
{
    var objType = obj.GetType();
    var prop = objType.GetProperty(propertyName);

    return prop.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

The above method works fine for calls like `GetPropertyValue(emp1, "FirstName")` but if I try `GetPropertyValue(emp1, "Address.AddressLine1")` it throws an exception because `objType.GetProperty(propertyName);` is not able to locate the nested object property value. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var address = GetPropertyValue(GetPropertyValue(emp1, "Address"), "AddressLine1");
```

Object Employee doesn't have a single property named "Address.AddressLine1", it has a property named "Address", which itself has a property named "AddressLine1".

Answer (score 36):

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    foreach (var prop in propertyName.Split('.').Select(s => obj.GetType().GetProperty(s)))
       obj = prop.GetValue(obj, null);

    return obj;
}
```

Thanks, I came here looking for an answer to the same problem. I ended up modifying your original method to support nested properties. This should be more robust than having to do nested method calls which could end up being cumbersome for more than 2 nested levels.

Comment: Is this a response to the other answer?

Comment: how can it works when the same "obj" is used for reflection type retrieving?

Answer (score 15):

This will work for unlimited number of nested property.

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    var _propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');

    for (var i = 0; i < _propertyNames.Length; i++)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var _propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(_propertyNames[i]);
            if (_propertyInfo != null)
                obj = _propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
            else
                obj = null;
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
GetPropertyValue(_employee, "Firstname");
GetPropertyValue(_employee, "Address.State");
GetPropertyValue(_employee, "Address.Country.Name");
```

Answer (score 14):

I use this method to get the values from properties (unlimited number of nested property) as below:

**"Property"**

**"Address.Street"**

**"Address.Country.Name"**

```
    public static object GetPropertyValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        if (src == null) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null.", "src");
        if (propName == null) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null.", "propName");

        if(propName.Contains("."))//complex type nested
        {
            var temp = propName.Split(new char[] { '.' }, 2);
            return GetPropertyValue(GetPropertyValue(src, temp[0]), temp[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            var prop = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
            return prop != null ? prop.GetValue(src, null) : null;
        }
    }
```

Here the Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PvKRH0

Answer (score 4):

Yet another variation to throw out there. Short & sweet, supports arbitrarily deep properties, handles null values and invalid properties:

```
public static object GetPropertyVal(this object obj, string name) {
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    var parts = name.Split(new[] { '.' }, 2);
    var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(parts[0]);
    if (prop == null)
        throw new ArgumentException($"{parts[0]} is not a property of {obj.GetType().FullName}.");

    var val = prop.GetValue(obj);
    return (parts.Length == 1) ? val : val.GetPropertyVal(parts[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Get Nest properties e.g., Developer.Project.Name

```
private static System.Reflection.PropertyInfo GetProperty(object t, string PropertName)
            {
                if (t.GetType().GetProperties().Count(p => p.Name == PropertName.Split('.')[0]) == 0)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("Property {0}, is not exists in object {1}", PropertName, t.ToString()));
                if (PropertName.Split('.').Length == 1)
                    return t.GetType().GetProperty(PropertName);
                else
                    return GetProperty(t.GetType().GetProperty(PropertName.Split('.')[0]).GetValue(t, null), PropertName.Split('.')[1]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I made an extension method on type for this propose:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static PropertyInfo GetSubProperty(this Type type, string treeProperty, object givenValue)
    {
        var properties = treeProperty.Split('.');
        var value = givenValue;

        foreach (var property in properties.Take(properties.Length - 1))
        {
            value = value.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(value);

            if (value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return value.GetType().GetProperty(properties[properties.Length - 1]);
    }

    public static object GetSubPropertyValue(this Type type, string treeProperty, object givenValue)
    {
        var properties = treeProperty.Split('.');
        return properties.Aggregate(givenValue, (current, property) => current.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(current));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Modified version of above to get the multilevel nested properties

```
private static System.Reflection.PropertyInfo GetProperty(object t, string PropertName, out object Value)
        {
            Value = "";
            var v = t.GetType().GetProperties();
            if (t.GetType().GetProperties().Count(p => p.Name == PropertName.Split('.')[0]) == 0)
                //throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("Property {0}, is not exists in object {1}", PropertName, t.ToString()));
                return null;
            if (PropertName.Split('.').Length == 1)
            {
                var Value1 = t.GetType().GetProperty(PropertName).GetValue(t, null);
                Value = Value1;//.ToString();
                return t.GetType().GetProperty(PropertName);
            }
            else
            {
                //return GetProperty(t.GetType().GetProperty(PropertName.Split('.')[0]).GetValue(t, null), PropertName.Split('.')[1], out Value);
                return GetProperty(t.GetType().GetProperty(PropertName.Split('.')[0]).GetValue(t, null), PropertName.Substring(PropertName.IndexOf('.') + 1, PropertName.Length - PropertName.IndexOf('.') - 1), out Value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for level 1 and level 2 object properties  e.g. `Firstname` and  `Address.AddressLine1`

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    object targetObject = obj;
    string targetPropertyName = propertyName;

    if (propertyName.Contains('.'))
    {
        string[] split = propertyName.Split('.');
        targetObject = obj.GetType().GetProperty(split[0]).GetValue(obj, null);
        targetPropertyName = split[1];
    }

    return targetObject.GetType().GetProperty(targetPropertyName).GetValue(targetObject, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with struct type in static class, So I must use this method GetNestedType, this is example code if you know property name, If you want to getAll you can use GetNestedTypes

ExpandoObject in this example just use for dynamic add property and value

```
private void ExtractValuesFromAppconstants(string keyName)
        {
            Type type = typeof(YourClass);
            var examination = type.GetNestedType(keyName);
            if (examination != null)
            {    
                var innerTypes = examination.GetNestedTypes();
                foreach (var innerType in innerTypes)
                {
                    Console.Writeline($"{innerType.Name}")
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the code posted by DevT almost did the trick but failed when there are collections involved e.g. Applicant.Addresses[0].FirstLine, so I added some code to fix this.  I am sure others can improve upon in.

```
public static object GetPropertyValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        if (src == null) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null.", "src");
        if (propName == null) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null.", "propName");

        if (propName.Contains("."))//complex type nested
        {
            var temp = propName.Split(new char[] { '.' }, 2);
            return GetPropertyValue(GetPropertyValue(src, temp[0]), temp[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (propName.Contains("["))
            {
                int iterator_start = propName.IndexOf('[');
                int iterator_end = propName.IndexOf(']');
                string iterator_value = propName.Substring(iterator_start + 1, iterator_end - iterator_start - 1);
                string string_to_remove = "[" + iterator_value + "]";
                int iterator_number = Convert.ToInt32(iterator_value);
                propName = propName.Replace(string_to_remove, "");

                var prop2 = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                Type type = prop2.PropertyType;
                if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                        == typeof(List<>))
                {
                    System.Collections.IList oTheList = (System.Collections.IList)prop2.GetValue(src, null);
                    return  oTheList[iterator_number];
                }
            }
           
            var prop = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            return prop != null ? prop.GetValue(src, null) : null;
            
                
        }
    }
```