# C# Debug Visualizer throug reflection: get value of property contained in complex object using Reflection

Tags: c#, debugging, list, reflection, spool

Suppose you have a list of 100 complex nested object, and you want to spool all the values of a propery (identified by a pattern) of some subobject.

IE:

```
lista_tipiclassifornitura[i].OpzioneTariffaria.Codice
```

The immediate windows doesn't support loop, so I want to create a public static method like this:

```
string Spool(object c, string propertyPath)
```

I'll call this method as follow:

```
Spool(lista_tipiclassifornitura, "lista_tipiclassifornitura[#].OpzioneTariffaria.Codice")
```

The procedure replace the # with a 0, 1, 2, ecc and should access the Property "OpzioneTariffaria" and the property of this "Codice" through MemberInfo.

This example could help me? 
[Getting Nested Object Property Value Using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535287/getting-nested-object-property-value-using-reflection)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It can be done.

This is how:

```
public class Address
{
    private string _addressLine1;
    public string AddressLine1
    {
        get { return _addressLine1; }
        set { _addressLine1 = value; }
    }

    private string _addressLine2;
    public string AddressLine2
    {
        get { return _addressLine2; }
        set { _addressLine2 = value; }
    }

    private string _city;
    public string City
    {
        get { return _city; }
        set { _city = value; }
    }

    private string _state;
    public string State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { _state = value; }
    }

    private string _zip;
    public string Zip
    {
        get { return _zip; }
        set { _zip = value; }
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }

    private string _middleName;
    public string MiddleName
    {
        get { return _middleName; }
        set { _middleName = value; }
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }

    private Address _employeeAddress;
    public Address EmployeeAddress
    {
        get { return _employeeAddress; }
        set { _employeeAddress = value; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    #region Variabili Globali

    static private Contesto contesto;

    static private string file = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFileLog"];

    static EniLoggerManager log;

    static private ArrayList ListaMessaggi = null;

    #endregion

    public static object GetPropertyValueComplete(object obj, string pattern)
    {
        pattern = "x.Lista[#].Opzione.Codice";
        List<string> s = new List<string>(pattern.Split('.'));


        return GetPropertyValueComplete(obj, s);
        return "";
    }

    private static object GetPropertyValueComplete(object obj, List<string> s)
    {
        s.RemoveAt(0);

        if (s.Count == 1)
            return GetPropertyValue(obj, s[0]);


        foreach (string s1 in s)
        {
            if(s1.Contains("#"))
            {
                object propertyValue = GetPropertyValue(obj, s1.Substring(0, s1.IndexOf('[')));
                List<object> list = new List<object>();
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        object value = GetPropertyValue(propertyValue, "Items", i);

                        if (value != null)
                            return GetPropertyValueComplete(value, (string) s);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else return GetPropertyValueComplete(obj, (string) s);
        }
    }

    public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        return GetPropertyValue(obj, propertyName, null);
    }

    public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName, int? index)
    {
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo prop = objType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        FieldInfo prop1 = objType.GetField(propertyName);

        if (prop == null && prop1 == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Proprietà {0} non trovata nel tipo {1}", propertyName, objType));
        else if (prop != null)
        {
            object propertyValue;
            if (index == null)
                propertyValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
            else
                propertyValue = prop.GetValue(obj, new Object[] {index});
            return propertyValue;
        }
        else if(prop1 != null)
            return prop1.GetValue(obj);
        return null;
    }
```