# Get Property Value from Nested Objects - Efficient Ways than Reflection

Tags: c#, algorithm, c#-4.0, reflection

My use case can have thousands of instances of a class. One of the properties in that class is also of the same type as that of a class and this can go on and on.

So I basically have a collection of nested classes. Now if I were to search a property's value, what would my options be.

I am finding recurssion as one([Getting Nested Object Property Value Using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535287/getting-nested-object-property-value-using-reflection)) and an exhaustive use of GetNestedTypes(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493t6h7t(v=vs.110).aspx) as other.

I read that reflection is expensive, so my question is, are there other ways to search the property without using reflection concept?

Comment: Can you show us a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with some sample inputs and expected outputs? _That will help us understand your problem before jumping into solution mode._

Comment: reflection can be expensive if its not done right. if you cache results you get, then using reflection wouldn't harm too much and would even perform as good as static approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expression trees to create an abstract syntax tree that you can then compile to a dynamic method. This performs very closely to regularly written code (from my testing it is many times faster then reflection). The creation of the dynamic method is expensive, so create once, use many times.

```
static Func<object,object> CreateDelegate(PropertyInfo[] path)
{
    var rootType = path.First().DeclaringType;
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    Expression access = Expression.Convert(param, rootType);
    foreach (var prop in path)
    {
        access = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(access, prop);
    }

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(
        Expression.Convert(access, typeof(object)),
        param
    ).Compile();

    return lambda;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = new[]
    {
        typeof(Root).GetProperty("Level1"),
        typeof(Level1).GetProperty("Level2"),
        typeof(Level2).GetProperty("Name")
    };

    var method = CreateDelegate(path);
    var data = new Root { Level1 = new Level1 { Level2 = new Level2 { Name = "Test" } } };
    var result = method(data);
}
```

References: [Dynamic Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod(v=vs.110).aspx), [Expression Tree-Compile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have built a dynamic expression kind of like you describe. It works great for e.g LessThan or GreaterThan expressions. But if I Add two expressions together, it uses the '&' sign, I require it to be the string 'AND'. Can you tell me how to fix this, please?